# How to fix XSS in website in url ? Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, security, security-patch

I can see that browsing url like this

```
https://www.anywebsite.com/?p=%3Cscript%3Ealert(document.cookie)%3C/script%3E
```

shows alert into browser window.

Is their any way to prevent it ? its XSS.

Comment: I can confirm that  by default this doesn't happen. I can conclude that this has something to do with tour custom code. I assume that `p` parameter is paging for something and I assume it should be an integer. Change your code that reads this parameter and convert it to int. Or better yet, if you are printing it somewhere make sure you escape the values (stip_tags for example if you don't want tags in there)

Comment: Hi , Glad to see your response @Marius, it's not just alert into browser but also add script into Html also & its appear in page as well.

Comment: Hello @Marius i can see in network tab that it contains  p = %3Cscript%3Ealert(document.cookie)%3C/script%3E  As query parameters but i am not able to find out where i am printing it, any thoughts ?

Comment: this means it might be safe. if it does not get shown anywayre in the page you might be save from xss

Comment: Thankyou @Marius It's fixed using  intval($_GET['p'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments

I can confirm that by default this doesn't happen. I can conclude that this has something to do with tour custom code. I assume that p parameter is paging for something and I assume it should be an integer. Change your code that reads this parameter and convert it to int. Or better yet, if you are printing it somewhere make sure you escape the values (stip_tags for example if you don't want tags in there)

If the script tag is not printed anywhere, this means that it is escaped somehow and you are safe from XSS